# What is the number of ordered pairs of real numbers (a,b) such that ......

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

Problem :

What is the number of ordered pairs of real numbers (a,b) such that $(a+ib)^{2002}=a-bi$

My approach :

Multiplying both sides by a+ib we get

$(a+ib)^{2003} = a^2+b^2$

$\Rightarrow (a+ib)= (a^2+b^2)^{1/2003}$

Now how to proceed further please guide thanks.

Comment: You might consider the $2003$rd roots of $1$ and how they might be related to this question

Comment: Take norms and you get $|z| \in \{0, 1\}$.  From there, you can consider polar form...

Answer (score 1):

Taking norms on both sides, $|z|^{2002} = |z| \implies |z| \in {0, 1}$.  So $a+ib = 0$ is clearly a solution and other ones are of form $e^{i \theta}$.  For these, from the period of the complex exponential,
$$e^{2002\cdot i\theta} = e^{-i\theta} \iff2002\theta =-\theta + 2n\pi \iff \theta = \frac{2n \pi}{2003}$$
where $n \in \mathbb Z$.